# Codeigniter Website Creator

Tags: php, codeigniter, architecture

Hi I'm looking for advice on how to achieve some multiple page functionality for a website builder i've written with the Codeigniter framework.

My initial attempt was creating an "add-on" domain in my host gator c-panel with the corresponding domain name. I then placed an .htaccess redirect to my Code Igniter view URI and it redirects fine. Here is the explanation I have of what is working at the moment.

www.afakecompany.com = the client domain name
www.myserver.com/CI/ = my CI directory

www.afakecompany.com domain register name servers point at my hostgator web hosting.
This hits the add-on domain i've setup called afakecompany.com
Which in turn triggers the .htaccess to redirect, this looks something along the lines of.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^afakecompany.myserver.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^afakecompany.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.afakecompany.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myserver.com/CI/website/view/1 [P,L]
```

This seemed ok at first, but I have a feeling it is long winded and I can only have one page redirect currently.

**Criteria I need to achieve is as follows:**

*Multiple page option* -  with the clients domain name showing them the correct url eg..
www.fakecompany.com/contact showing in the browser but actually grabbing the content from  myserver.com/CI/website/view/1/contact ('not sure how ci will route this stuff yet')

*Scaleability* - Is having a new add-on domain for each new website a bad idea? It seems it to me. Also if I had to relocate hosting or modify something in all the .htaccess files it would be a nightmare

I am new to web development so I apologize for any face palming that may have occurred on account of my noobness. So I ask thee.. How could I achieve this/do it better?

Comment: let me know if you did find a solution

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at getting a [reseller account](http://www.hostgator.com/resellers.shtml), since any home-brewed solution might pose a security risk if you implement it incorrectly across multiple client's accounts. A reseller account is nice because you basically sell access to your server resources (bandwidth, space, etc.) but the client's accounts are isolated.

Comment: If i'm understanding correctly with this option. We would have to create individual sites for each client? 

I'm looking for a website factory solution. Fill out a form with content and options and hit submit. Also global templates that span over all clients sites that I could change in one place. Would that be possible with the reseller account?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm pretty sure that some reseller accounts (not HostGator's as far as I can tell) can offer you API's that your application can call to set up accounts. I personally have no experience with reseller accounts, but they are something to consider.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll dig into it a bit more.